# How to solve for $e^{-x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm sure I learned this at some point, I think it has something to do with $\log$-ing the function. Could someone please walk me through it?

$$0=4x^2e^{-x^2}-2e^{-x^2}$$

By the way, this is the second derivative, and I'm looking for points of inflection. I know how to do that part, but I just need a refresher on $e$.

UPDATE: Thanks to everyone who answered, but I was really hoping for a more general explanation of how to solve for $x$ when you have $e^x$.

Comment: Wait, does it just mean $2x^2=1$?

Comment: Are you trying to solve for $e^{-x}$ or are you just trying to solve the equation? The only solutions are $x = 0$, $x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, as can be seen from re-arranging to $4x^2 e^{-x^2} = 2e^{-x^2}$ and cancelling $e^{-x^2}$ from both sides, which is justified since $e^{-x^2} > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John, very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's
$$
0 = (4x^2 - 2) e^{-x^2}
$$
The $e$ term is never zero, so the only roots happen when $4x^2 - 2 = 0$.

To answer the question you actually asked: if you had to solve, say,

$$
e^{-x^2} = 1.3
$$
you could indeed take the natural logarithm of both sides, to get 
\begin{align}
\ln(e^{-x^2}) &= \ln(1.3)\\
-x^2 &= \ln(1.3)\\
x^2 &= -\ln(1.3)\\
x^2 &= \ln(\frac{1}{1.3})\\
x &= \pm \sqrt{\ln(\frac{1}{1.3})}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can divide both sides by $e^{-x^{2}} $ which is none-zero for every x, and then you are left with a polynomial.